Negating 'any' filter on extensions with Graph API causes a 500 internal error
Im retriving calendar event from MS 365 with Graph API where i filter the Events by start/stop.
I also filter on extensions like this.
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"start/dateTime ge '{startDateString}' and end/dateTime le '{endDateString}' and extensions/any(f:id eq 'com.zxc.zxcExtensions')";

This works just fine.
But now i want to negate the extension filter. And from reading the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=csharp#any-operator) i assumed that it would work using 'not' like this.
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"start/dateTime ge '{startDateString}' and end/dateTime le '{endDateString}' and not(extensions/any(f:id eq 'com.zxc.zxcExtensions'))";

But that generates a 500 internal error.
'An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.'
I have also tried removing the start/stop filter like this resulting in the same 500 error.
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"not(extensions/any(f:id eq 'com.zxc.zxcExtensions'))";

Am i doing something wrong? Or somthing that isn't allowed?
If so, is there a workaround?
EDIT: Complete code for retriving the Events
var events = await graphServiceClient
    .Users[user]
    .Events
    .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "Id", "Subject", "Start", "End", "Organizer", "createdDateTime", "lastModifiedDateTime" };
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "Extensions($filter=id eq 'com.zxc.zxcExtensions')" };
        //requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"start/dateTime ge '{startDateString}' and end/dateTime le '{endDateString}' and extensions/any(f:id eq 'com.zxc.zxcComExtensions')";
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"start/dateTime ge '{startDateString}' and end/dateTime le '{endDateString}' and not(extensions/any(f:id eq 'com.zxc.zxcComExtensions'))";
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { $"start/dateTime" };
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 9999;
    });

EDIT 2:
I have tried enabling "advanced queries" by adding this code to the request. Unfortunately it gives the same negative result.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=csharp
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");


Could you edit your question and include your complete code in it? Are you trying to retrieve the events that don't have specific extension?

@Sridevi Yes, im trying to filter out the Events that have a spesific extension. I have added the full method call for retriving the Events

AFAIK, directly filtering out events with specific extension by negating 'any' filter is not supported as of now. Alternatively, post-filter the events after fetching them or perform multiple API calls for events with and without the extension as a workaround.
